# HTML - div won't extend across page

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a bar that extends across the entire page, but I can't get that working. I've tried multiple things like `position: relative;` and `margin: 0;` but none work. Here is what I have now in the CSS:

```css
html, body
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.navigation-bar
{
 font-size: 46px;
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 display: inline;
 background-color: #F4F4F4;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100vw;
}
.navigation-bar-button
{
 display: inline;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 30px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
.navigation-bar-title-text
{
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
   <div class="navigation-bar-title-text"><font color="#444444">my</font><font color="#ADADAD">phys</font><font color="#DDDDDD">ed</font></div> <button type="button" class="navigation-bar-button">Home</button>
   <hr width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
 </div>
  </body>
```

But the background color still won't go the end of the screen. Any idea of how to fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make `navigation-bar` as block and make button to float right to move towards right

```css
html, body
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
.navigation-bar
{
 font-size: 46px;
 font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
 display:block;
 background-color: #F4F4F4;
 margin: 0;
 width: 100vw;
  
}
.navigation-bar-button
{
 display: inline-block;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 30px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 background-color: #D8D8D8;
  float:right;
  margin:5px;
}
.navigation-bar-title-text
{
 display: inline;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
   <div class="navigation-bar-title-text"><font color="#444444">my</font><font color="#ADADAD">phys</font><font color="#DDDDDD">ed</font></div> <button type="button" class="navigation-bar-button">Home</button>
   <hr width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
 </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: When I do `float: right;` for my button, it doesn't become vertically centered inside the div anymore. Any way to fix this? `vertical-align: middle;` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: fix it through giving margin  like this margin : 10px 5px 5px 5px;

Answer (score 3):

make `display block` in `.navigation-bar` class it will works

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't want to use `display: inline` since it will inline your elements. In this case you surely need a block element to get the it to the full width. Checkout the snippet below with `display: flex`:

```css
I'm trying to make a bar that extends across the entire page, but I can't get that working. I've tried multiple things like position: relative; and margin: 0; but none work. Here is what I have now in the CSS:

html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.navigation-bar
{
    font-size: 46px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
.navigation-bar-button
{
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
.navigation-bar-title-text
{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
      <div class="navigation-bar-title-text"><font color="#444444">my</font><font color="#ADADAD">phys</font><font color="#DDDDDD">ed</font></div> <button type="button" class="navigation-bar-button">Home</button>
    </div>
  </body>
```

You can use `justify-content` in order to position your elements.

Answer (score 2):

use `display:block` for `.navigation-bar`

```css
html, body
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.navigation-bar
{
    font-size: 46px;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    display: block;
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100vw;
}
.navigation-bar-button
{
    display: inline;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    font-size: 30px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #D8D8D8;
}
.navigation-bar-title-text
{
    display: inline;
}
```

```html
 <body>
    <div class="navigation-bar">
      <div class="navigation-bar-title-text"><font color="#444444">my</font><font color="#ADADAD">phys</font><font color="#DDDDDD">ed</font></div> <button type="button" class="navigation-bar-button">Home</button>
      <hr width="100%" style="margin: 0; padding: 0">
    </div>
  </body>
```